# Filtered indices: Why include the filtered-on field?

Tags: sql-server-2008, index, execution-plan

This just drives me mad.

Consider a simple table with irrelevant columns removed:

```sql
create table boxes (
  row_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  location varchar(15) null,
  dismantled bit not null default 0,
  rank int not null default 0
  /* irrelevant columns, text and numbers */
)
```

For a certain important query, I want a filtered index:

```sql
create nonclustered index anindex ON boxes (rank)
where (dismantled=0 and location is null)
```

This creates an index that contains about 150 records out of about 150k. Which is fine.

Now we query the table:

```sql
select top (1) row_id
from boxes
where dismantled = 0 and location is null
order by rank;
```

The execution plan is weird. Index scan on `anindex` accompanied by a bookmark lookup using the seeked `row_id` to confirm that `location` is `null`. Records that pass the lookup are selected.

Why on Earth? `location` is `null` by the very definition of the used index, is it not?

Now, if I do a stupid thing and include `location` in the filtered index...

```sql
create nonclustered index anindex ON boxes (location, rank)
where (dismantled=0 and location is null)
```

Then all of a sudden the execution plan is great, index seek on `anindex` with no lookups.

This is just one example, I stumble upon this issue every time I want to use a filtered index. Every time I end up forced to include the useless fields, upon which the index is filtered, to the list of indexed fields, and only then the server uses the index properly; otherwise, it either scans it or ignores it completely.

What gives? Is it a recommended practice to include the useless fields?

Comment: It looks to me that lookup is performed because you have `rank` column in your query which is not part of the index

Comment: I am having such issues from time to time as well, so I am not using this filtered index thing as much as I would like. Instead, I use indexed views or normal indexes.

Comment: @a1ex07 How is `rank` not part of the index?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov Me too, I use index hints for that normally now, since the filtered indexes are usually tuned for a particular query

Comment: @GSerg: nm, sorry, I missed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been previously raised on Connect and [Closed as "Won't Fix"](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/643850/filtered-index-execution-plan-is-not-optimized).

> We'll close this because it seems a narrow scenario and we don't see
>   doing anything about it in the forseeable future.

That's quite disappointing IMO. Perhaps upvote and comment that item.

**Edit:** BOL has [an example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) of using `WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL` in a filtered index and that does **not** do a key lookup but replacing `IS NOT NULL` with `IS NULL` does lead to a lookup so it appears as though *sometimes* it is avoided...

Comment: Yes, it *sometimes* does the right thing. For instance, it does the right thing in regard of `dismantled` in my example, I don't have to include it in the index.

Comment: I mostly use filtered indexes to enforce conditional uniqueness. Other than that, I was encountering issues and gave up on it for now. How do you use them?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov To enforce uniqueness ignoring null fields, yes. Sometimes for actual queries though, at which point I have to test to see what filtered columns I will need to include.